# Delaunay Triangulation

Tags: graph-theory, computational-geometry, discrete-geometry, triangulation

Wikipedia on [Delaunay Triangulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delaunay_triangulation) says:

```
"In the plane[...], if there are b vertices on the convex hull, then any 
triangulation of the points has at most 2n − 2 − b triangles, plus one 
exterior face."
```

Here n is the total number of vertices in the plane.

I can't see how they obtained this result when I use Euler's formula 1=V-E+F. So V=n then F=1-n+E. what is face exterior?

Comment: Outside the convex hull, to infinity.

Comment: I don't understand.

Answer (score 3):

[Euler's formular](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planar_graph#Euler's_formula) for planar graphs with $n$ vertices, $e$ edges and $f$ faces says that $2 = n - e + f$. Note that $f$ includes the outer, unbounded face to infinity, too. So we have $f-1$ triangles and a $b$-gon.

We can assign to each edge two tokens; one for each incident face. The number of tokens can be counted per face, too: $3(f-1)$ for $f-1$ triangles and $b$ for the outer face, so $3 (f-1) + b = 2e$.

Then we have $4 = 2n - 2e + 2f = 2n -f -k + 3$, and hence $f-1 = 2n -2 -b$, which is the number of triangles.

Answer (score 2):

The exterior face is the green area.

[image]

Comment: how do I derive the formula 2n − 2 − b?

Comment: @cripto: what are $V,F,E$ ?

Comment: V=vertex, F=faces and E=edges

Comment: @cripto: I was sure you would answer this !

Comment: I don't  known where to use 1=V-E+F

Comment: @cripto: express $V,F,E$ differently.

Comment: but I have to use 1=V-E+F or 2=V-E+F